# Hiding history of commands in solaris

Tags: security, bash, shell, solaris

is it totally possible to completely hide a shell's history or prevent it from logging?

i  trying to find who renamed a directory and when. the problem is my dba renamed back the directory and didn't note down the time and date of the directory. it could have helped a lot.

Comment: If the rename required `sudo` you might find the command in the system logs. Of course, if your users have unrestricted `sudo` access, they could have run `sudo sh` with no history from the interactive session.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` stores command entries in `HISTFILE` (by default *`~/.bash_history`*) and has a *fixed* size of how many to keep - `HISTFILESIZE` (by default *`500`*). If the commands, one types, exceed that number, then history of those is lost.

Commands can also be ignored, see `HISTIGNORE`, as well as commands that start with a leading space - see `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace`. Those are not ever stored in `HISTFILE`.

If you use some logging mechanism, then avoiding logging a command or blocking the log entry, would depend on that particular software.

Comment: it's just a plain vanilla solaris 10. i'm relying on "last", bash history, and still looking elsewhere for some logs.  the thing is, the person's ~/.bash_history is only a couple of lines long whereas he has been active in the system since Jan of this year.

Comment: well, he's either not using that shell (ie he might be using zsh..), or not using the shell at all, or he likes privacy and clears the history often (`history -c`, history is a shell builtin command).

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't depend on Solaris but really on the shell used.

Some shells like the legacy Bourne shell (/bin/sh on Solaris 10 and older) just do not record at all command history so you are out of luck in that case.

Other shells might record a defined number of commands on disk depending on the user configuration (savehist with csh, HISTFILE/HISTSIZE with ksh and bash). ksh records the history in real time while bash records it on shell exit so you might lose the history if the shell dies abruptly. Bash has also some setting that would prevent some commands not to appear on the history (HISTCONTROL, HISTIGNORE, HISTFILESIZE). If you have more than one interactive shell running, commands will be lost if the histappend shell option is not set with bash.